# Is directshow CBaseRenderer thread safe?

Tags: c++, winapi, synchronization, directshow, deadlock

I'm working with a simple directshow filter that is derived from `CBaseRenderer` in the directshow baseclasses and I'm getting deadlocks in this class.

I've had a good google, and found someone who's had the [exact same problem](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/directshow-real-deadlocks-continued-help-27427592.html) (with a deadlock between the `InterfaceLock` in Stop, and the `RendererLock` in `Receive`) but he didn't get any responses, which suggests its a rare circumstance that he and I have got in our code (rather than a bug in MSs base class).

So, has anyone else seen this problem?
Should I derive my filter (which doesn't do that much TBH) from `CBaseRenderer` or go straight to the `CBaseFilter/CBaseInputPin` classes?
If I should override `WaitForReceiveToComplete`, what should I put in there?

I'm going back to basics and looking at the dump sample filter, but I'd still be interested in responses from people who have experiences using `CBaseRenderer`.

Comment: There might be a deadlock there, but if you derive your own renderer - you have all the source code to resolve it (e.g. by not holding outer lock, or unlock it while waiting for messages etc).

Comment: @RomanR. I don't hold any of the CBaseRenderer's locks, I do have my own (as specified in the docs) but I'm trying to understand what I should do to make the base class work... maybe I should start to hold the base classes locks. I shall have to try it.

Comment: My understanding is that you are hitting deadlock around `m_InterfaceLock`. I never had it myself, hence no solution off the top of my head, but looking at code it looks possible. I'd say the problem is `for` look inside `WaitForReceiveToComplete` which needs to run with unlocked lock - this is something I'd try to add into BaseClasses code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the problem might be around this loop in BaseClasses\renbase.cpp:

```
void CBaseRenderer::WaitForReceiveToComplete()
{
    // NOTE: m_InterfaceLock is locked higher on the call stack

    for (;;) {
        if (!m_bInReceive) {
            break;
        }

        MSG msg;
        //  Receive all interthread snedmessages
        PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_NULL, WM_NULL, PM_NOREMOVE);

        // TODO: Unlock m_InterfaceLock until the end of the loop 

        Sleep(1);
    }
```

The comments above explain the problem - an endless loop might be taking a concurrent thread trying to enter `m_InterfaceLock`.

If this is the case, sleeping unlocked there might give a chance to break through.

Comment: in the end I went back to basics and made a new filter based on the dump sample. It works, though there's still a little bit of thread niggles I had to resolve in the pin's Receive method, but at least I am in control of the locks now. Any class that has 2 locks and a busy wait on a bool variable isn't well written IMHO.

Comment: That should have been an event instead of bool... but we have what we have. The code is 10 or maybe 15 years old, folks at MS don't update this code base without severe reasons.